# couchdb document update handler single field

Tags: couchdb, nosql

I want to create a design document which will make the update of a single field (of a document) while it gives back the entire document. In my database, an example of document is the following:

```
{
    "domain": "google.it",
    "controlled":"0"
}
```

I’d like to do a query such as:

```
function(doc) {
    if(doc.controlled=="0") {
       doc['controlled']='1';
       return[doc];
    }
}
```

I have read CouchDB supports the Document Update Handler but I can’t create one. Has someone any guide for beginners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code below implies doc already exists.

```
function(doc,req) {
    if (!doc) return [null,"Doc does not exists! Create it first."];
    doc.controlled = doc.controlled=="0"?"1":"0";
    return [doc,"Ok, Updated"]
}
```

You can use req.query.yourquerystringparameter to update your doc based on request query string parameters

Read [official documentation on update functions](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/couchapp/ddocs.html#update-functions) for details

You find an [easy to start guide here](http://guide.couchdb.org/)
or a more advanced [couchdb tutorial here](https://www.smileupps.com/store/apps/chatty-couchapp-tutorial)

Comment: @Ernesto You can accept and upvote an answer when it is helpful.